# How to make iOS application appear in list of suggested applications after screenshot?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like my app to appear in the list of suggested applications that can be seen after taking a screenshot in iOS.

For example, currently when a user takes a screenshot and taps the send/export button, a modal appears over the bottom half of the screen which contains a list of applications that the user can export the image to, and even a *more* button which contains further app options.

What needs to be done in swift iOS app project (using xcode ide) in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display your app in the`UIActivityViewController`, you need to create a `Share Extension` for your application. To create a share extension for your project, go to `file > new > target > Share Extension`. You can refer to [Apple's Documentation for share extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)!